# Wait till all the promises are resolved / Firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

Could you tell how to wait till all the promises are resolved? At this moment it moves to next line without completing below operation. I need to fully complete the `foreach` and after that move to the next line.So how can I do it?

```
forEach(project.projectDetail.memberList, async (m) => {
        const memberDocumentRef: firebase.firestore.DocumentReference = this.fireStore.doc(`members/${m.id}`).ref;
        await this.fireStore.firestore.runTransaction(transaction => {
          return transaction.get(memberDocumentRef).then(memberDoc => {
            let currentProjects: Project[] = memberDoc.data().projects;
            const finalProjects = filter(currentProjects, (p: Project) => { return p.id != project.projectDetail.id; });//projects Without Updated Project
            finalProjects.push(project.projectDetail);
            transaction.update(memberDocumentRef, { projects: Object.assign({}, finalProjects) });//update projects on each member
          });
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Promise.all`, and change the `forEach` to a `map`:

```
// This promise.all returns a promise that will resolve when all the inner promises complete.
// You can either put dependent code in its .then method, or await it:

 await Promise.all(project.projectDetail.memberList.map(async (m: Member) => {
    const memberDocumentRef: firebase.firestore.DocumentReference = this.fireStore.doc(`members/${m.id}`).ref;
    await this.fireStore.firestore.runTransaction(transaction => {
      return transaction.get(memberDocumentRef).then(memberDoc => {
        let currentProjects: Project[] = memberDoc.data().projects;
        const finalProjects = filter(currentProjects, (p: Project) => { return p.id != project.projectDetail.id; });//projects Without Updated Project
        finalProjects.push(project.projectDetail);
        transaction.update(memberDocumentRef, { projects: Object.assign({}, finalProjects) });//update projects on each member
      });
    });
  }));
```

Comment: Hey, I notice you edited the answer. Still looks right but I want to note that if you return the `this.fireStore...` promise instead of awaiting it, everything will still work but you won't have to declare the map function as async (unless you prefer it that way).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Above code is working perfectly fine for me :)