# Simultaneous firestore queries wait till the other has finished

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

In my react-native app I am querying a collection for a very small amount of data that, on its own, usually takes <1 second to complete. I also want to simultaneously query a separate collection for a much larger amount of data (~1MB) which usually completes in 5-10 seconds.

My issue is that if I query the large collection before the smaller query has completed, the smaller query will not complete until the larger one does.

My smaller (Prices) query:

```
export const getPrices = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: GETTING_PRICES });
    let prices;
    firestore
      .collection('settings-daily-market')
      .orderBy('MarketDate', 'desc')
      .limit(1)
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const priceUpdated = moment(doc.data().MarketDate).format(
            'MMMM D, YYYY'
          );
          const Pd = doc.data().PdMarket;
          const Pt = doc.data().PtMarket;
          const Rh = doc.data().RhMarket;
          const PdHedge = doc.data().PdHedge;
          const PtHedge = doc.data().PtHedge;
          const RhHedge = doc.data().RhHedge;
          prices = { Pd, Pt, Rh, PdHedge, PtHedge, RhHedge, priceUpdated };
        });
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_PRICES, payload: prices });
      });
  };
};
```

My larger (Catalog) query:

```
export const getCatalog = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: GETTING_CATALOG });
    let completeCatalog = {};
    firestore
      .collection('records-catalytic-converters')
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(
          doc => (completeCatalog[doc.data().Name] = doc.data())
        );
        dispatch({ type: GET_CATALOG, payload: completeCatalog });
      });
  };
};
```

Essentially, the FETCH_PRICES and GET_CATALOG dispatches happen at the same time despite one (theoretically) completing long before the other.

I have a hunch that this might be related to another issue I am having. While the .forEach() loop in the Catalog query runs, my app is unresponsive and any user inputs get registered after the Catalog query completes.

Is there a way to make the forEach loop asynchronous?

Comment: You can use Promises and Promise.all[] to make sure alll the api calls have been completed.

Comment: That would indeed be `Promise.all()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47552876/multiple-firestore-queries-single-promise-callback, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48310677/wait-till-all-the-promises-are-resolved-firestore

Comment: Could you help me understand what that would look like? I tried simply calling `Promise.all([getPrices(), getCatalog()])` but I'm not sure what the `.then()` portion should look like... In the example that @FrankvanPuffelen linked it looks like the OP wants to resolve the promises from his database queries all in the same manner. I need different resolutions for each query.

Comment: Your `then` will get an array in that case, with the first element being the result of `getPrices()` and the second element being the result of `getCatalog()`.